# using provider : selector with list in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

My question is about using provider in flutter, now I have a list of 100 items and in every time I get any update, the provider replace the whole list.
So, my question is how to use provider in a list without needing to re-rendering the whole list items?!!

Answer (score 0):

see Consumer/Selector at https://pub.dev/packages/provider

```
Foo(
  child: Consumer<A>(
    builder: (_, a, child) {
      return Bar(a: a, child: child);
    },
    child: Baz(),
  ),
)
```

> In this example, only Bar will rebuild when A updates. Foo and Baz
> won't unnecessarily rebuild.